# Silverlight - Get Telerik RadGridView column and Set content for toggle button

Tags: silverlight, telerik

I have a Telerik RadGridView and wish I could set some column's `IsVisible` property to false or true when I click a toggle button.

1. I can only get the column by `grid.Columns[1].IsVisible = False`.
   I wanted to set it like this `grid.Columns["ColumnName"].IsVisible`, but failed. Is that possible?
   I use `x:Name = "ColumnName"`
2. How can I set content property for this toggle button, for example as "Display" at first and when click it, content change to "Hide"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use UniqueName instead of x:Name